# May 1st new iTunes submitting regulation

Tags: ios, retina-display, iphone-5

1) iPhone 5 (4 inch screen)

According to the explanation on page 51 in iOS Human Interface Guidelines,
we shouldn’t use the extra space to display an additional bar or banner.
However, we would like to make the extra space more artistic in order to
improve the design quality of the game. In fact, we are going to decorate
the space with beautiful design patterns. 
By doing this, we are sure that we can provide rich game experience
to our customers. Are there any problems to implement this artwork?

2) Retina Display

We think we should make our existing image resources( App icon,
App icon for the AppStore,Launch image) adjust to the Retina Display.

In addition, we might need to add the @2ⅹ suffix to all files and
scale up all image resources to 200%. We would like to know
the details about the requirements to meet the criteria for Retina Display.
What are we supposed to do?

does somebody know the MINIMUM regulation which take effect from May 1?
this is my first question.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## 1) I don't think there won't be any issue in adding artwork for iphone 5. But ensure it doesn't screw up look & feel in iPhone 4 ( 3.5 " screen)

## 2) Here is the apple spec which explains about retina images

iPhone -> App icon (required)
NON RETINA: 57 x 57 pixels
RETINA: 114 x 114 pixels (@2x)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html

Another point you need to take care is ensure to remove [uidevice currentdevice uniqueidentifier] ( deprecated in iOS 5)

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: biggest problem the game im working on is from another old prat-home and we don't have any good resolution file for 4-inch retina. and the program point the position by absolute location. thanks anyway.